# customer use real credit card information against paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

customer make payment (with real/valid credit card) on test website that is linked with paypal sandbox account. paypal notfied them that $200 is deducted from their account with proper transaction id.

I can see that transaction id in sandbox business account but question is if real money is deducted from their accounts?

Same question if they use paypal to pay us instead of credit card while site was operating under test mode and linked with paypal sandbox business account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. It is a self contained area for you to test all your paypal applications

From the paypal [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/)

"The PayPal Sandbox is a self-contained, virtual testing environment that mimics the live PayPal production environment. It provides a shielded space where you can initiate and watch your application process the requests you make to the PayPal APIs without touching any live PayPal accounts."

Here is a link to some test credit card accounts paypal recommend you use with development of your paypal application

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payflow/payflow-pro/payflow-pro-testing/

Comment: The link is now dead and this info may be out-of-date.